# how to get smaller top and bottom page margins for a single (float) page?

Tags: floats, margins

I have a tall figure that I want to appear on a separate page, but NOT at the very end of the article, and want smaller top and bottom margins *only* for that float page. I can use `\begin{figure}[p]` to put it on a float page.

I did try tricks such as `\newgeometry ... \restoregeometry` but they either cut the text on the previous page (see MWE below), or affect the margins on the page before/after (I couldn't reproduce this one in the MWE). In the MWE below the text on the 2nd page is cut, showing only 4 lines of text, then I get the figure on the next page, then text again. I'd like the text to still flow normally, i.e. the 2nd page to have full text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[left=1.8in,right=1.8in,top=1.75in,bottom=1.65in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \blindtext[1]
  \blindtext[1]
  \blindtext[1]
  \blindtext[1]
  \newgeometry{top=10mm, bottom=15mm}
  \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[height=10cm]{image.png}
  \caption{bleh}
  \end{figure}
  \restoregeometry
  \blindtext[1]
  \blindtext[1]
  \blindtext[1]
  \blindtext[1]
  \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Without `\newgeometry` I can get/emulate a smaller top margin by using negative `\vspace` and still have the text flow without being cut on the previous page, but the bottom margin is the biggest culprit, because I want to push the page number lower.

I'd be grateful for some hints.

Comment: Does `\enlargethispage{1cm}` work?

Comment: The use of `\newgeometry ... \restoregeometry` should be fine. Could you please create a MWE that reproduces the problem you described (that this method affects the page before and after too)?

Comment: @RuixiZhang I added an MWE which shows the text on the previous page is cut (I couldn't reproduce the prev/next page margin problem). I'd still be happy if I could fix that problem.

Comment: @marmot no, it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that `\blindtext` creates a large single paragraph instead of multiple paragraphs.

I'm not sure why, but the extra `\clearpage` at the end appears to be needed. I did notice that afterpage redefines `\clearpage` internally.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1.8in,right=1.8in,top=1.75in,bottom=1.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \afterpage{\newgeometry{top=10mm, bottom=15mm}
    \begin{figure}[p]
      \includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image}
      \caption{bleh}
    \end{figure}
    \restoregeometry\clearpage}
  \lipsum[4-10]
\end{document}
```

---

This solution overlays a minipage and footer on an otherwise empty page.  The firat `\raisebox` together with the `\vfill`s move to the center of the revised text area.  The second `\raisebox` does the footer, assuming that geometry wouldn't have changed `\footskip`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1.8in,right=1.8in,top=1.75in,bottom=1.65in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]% #1 = figure or table
  {\def\@captype{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \afterpage{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
    \null\vfill
    \noindent\raisebox{\dimexpr 1.75in-1.65in}[10mm][15mm]% center of new text area
      {\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \setcaptype{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image}
        \caption{bleh}
     \end{minipage}}
    \vfill% add footer manually
    \noindent\raisebox{\dimexpr 15mm-1.65in-\footskip}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\thepage}}
    \newpage}
  \lipsum[4-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad: the actual MWE i wrote had four `\blindtext[1]` which I changed to `\blindtext[4]` when I posted without checking. Apologies! Fixed the MWE. The problem I describe is in fact there. The `\clearpage` does not fix it for me.

Comment: hmmm, using several `\blindtext[1]` instead of `\lipsum[1-4]` behaves differently. Text is cut in the former but not latter case. The latter puts the figure kind of where it should be, but the next page has no page number. In my article the text is cut though.

Comment: I didn't notice the page number was missing.  I was just happy that the column was ending at the right place.  Alas, this deals with the intertices of \output and \afterpage which are beyond me.  It really would be easier to just overlay the margins for one page.

Comment: @Normadize this is because `\aftergroup` is missing; this must be inserted before `\restoregeometry`.